# Why was this spam flag on an answer declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, spam, moderation

I flagged an answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3041770/6879826) as spam; the flag was declined, but a moderator deleted the question minutes later. Here is the body of the now-deleted answer:

> No, not at all. I created a platform called [Clojurecademy](https://clojurecademy.com/) which aims
>   to teach Clojure programming language(which is a dialect of Lisp) and
>   it has interactive(hands-on) teaching model like Codecademy does.
>
> You can start with it and you will see that how easy that is.

The link appears to be dead, so maybe this is why the answer was deleted even though my flag was declined? Or maybe the moderator didn't feel like a -100 rep penalty was warranted for this user?

But, there are at least ten other answers by this user that seem to exist primarily to promote their website: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563703/6879826), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563881/6879826), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46575216/6879826), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46588420/6879826), [five](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46590436/6879826), [six](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46595123/6879826), [seven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46629978/6879826), [eight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46631373/6879826), [nine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46633143/6879826), [ten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46653300/6879826).

Granted, the user indicated in the post that I flagged that they had created the website; this is also true in some (but not all) of the above ten answer posts. But even so, all of this feels very spammy to me, and I don't think that these are the kind of answers that we want on the site.

Flagging as spam seems like the right action here, but maybe a moderator flag would have been better to call attention to a pattern. Do I just have the wrong idea of what constitutes spam?

Comment: Did the mod include a message in the declined response?

Comment: @psubsee2003 In my experience mods never bother to do that.

Comment: Bit of a corner-case.  It is certainly quite spammy, but the author has contributed many useful posts before.  Slapping him with a -100 rep penalty might put an unfortunate end to that.  Your flag had otherwise the desirable effect, the mod also put a stop to more spammy post getting added by closing the question.  Mission accomplished.

Comment: all of the questions on answers you linked to are close worthy (except for possibly "Can I use Common Lisp for SICP...") but I don't see your close votes on these, why is that?

Comment: ^^ Nearly identical situation — spam flag declined, despite a clear presence of multiple spammy answers. Consensus is to modflag in situations like this.

Comment: @TylerH Sometimes I get comments from them, although typically for special flags ("revert war is going on", "I suggest migration to...", "revenge chain down for this meta post", "hairsplitting", "advocates criminality", "pride for power misuse") and so on.

Comment: @TylerH "mods never bother to do that". Please don't generalize. I use to do it when it's tangential. Of course some users tend to flag as spam just to get a free downvote too. That doesn't seem to be the case here. Another possibility is to clear the spam flag (but you cannot add a reason) that makes the flag "disputed" not "declined"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm not generalizing; I said "in my experience", which is an absolute, data-driven statement.

Comment: I hope that next time your flag is declined, you get a reason. True, I declined a spam flag today, but I think the person mixed up "spam" with "downvote". So the canned "no evidence to support it" applied. For instance I declined with "the link on the site is part of the question. The question is bad, too broad, but not spam" for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56531633/recaptcha-adding-code-to-wordpress-site-xtheme

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"But, there are at least ten other answers by this user that seem to exist primarily to promote their website"

Had you said *that* in a custom flag, odds are your flag wouldn't have been declined.  But just one answer referencing a product they're affiliated with isn't spam.  You're allowed to reference a product you're affiliated with as long as it's relevant to the question an you disclose the affiliation.  It's the repeated references to a product in a large percentage of posts that turns it into spam, so that's what your flag needs to include for the flag to be valid.

Answer (score 5):

I actually had to do this yesterday. We had a user post links on three separate SE sites and they asked a "question" on SO about said software, sans link. What you need to keep in mind is that spam/rude flags are **only validated if they're obvious**. If there's *any* possibility of spam being mistaken for NAA/LQP, just mod flag and include the details.

If you spot a pattern of spam, however, and want some bigger guns to help make your case, [Charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) would love to help. Per this question I've added that domain to the watch list so they can't post it again without someone noticing.

Comment: yeah, validating a spam flag is serious. Better let the "spammer" get away than leaving a spam flag against some innocent link only answerer. We'll catch them later if they continue

Comment: thanks and TBH I don't see how this is a duplicate. Since the answers to the other question are "this is spam". Here it's not spam, just link-only that _looks_ like spam.